# PHP от HTML в одном файле

Tags: html, php

Как сделать так, чтобы после ввода текстовой переменной test на странице index.php

```
//Это index.php
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="button" name="button">
</form>
```

происходила обработка php, и ответ, то есть без редиректов. То есть как сделать `action="index.php"`

---

вот исходник:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Главная страница</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$test=$_POST[text];
echo  "Вы ввели:".$test;
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" value="Введите текст здесь..." name="text">
<input type="button" name="button">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Отображается:

```
Вы ввели:
//Тут форма(текст и кнопка)
```

А мне надо чтобы сначало была просто форма, а потом просто надпись `"Вы ввели <переменная из формы>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам ответил на свой вопрос)
оставь пустым action, чтобы файл сам себя обрабатывал ))

после формы напиши такой код:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    if($text == '')
         echo 'Заполни поле';
    else
         echo $text;
}
```